# passing a NULL as an argument in a function

Tags: c++

i created a book class which i having being working on as part of my assignment but its seems have being having one problem which i am failing to understand in my code below,
this is my code

```
private:
Book (string N = " ", int p = 100, string A = "",
        string P = "", string T = "", int Y = 2000)
{
    cout << "Book constructor start " << N << endl;
    Title=N;
    pages=p;
    Author=A;
    Publisher=P;
    Type=T;
    Yearpublished=Y;
}

~Book(void)
{
    cout << "Book destructor start " << Title << endl;
    system("pause");
}

public:
static Book * MakeBook(string N = "", int p = 100, string A = "",
        string P = "",string T = "",int Y = 2000)
{
    return new Book(N,p,A,P,T,Y);
}

static void DelBook(Book * X) {
    delete X;
}
```

In the above code is a constructor and destructor, my question is what happens when I pass a `NULL` as an argument in the `stactic void DelBook` function? like this below

```
static void DelBook(NULL)
{
    delete NULL;
}
```

How can I make it compile if its possible to pass a NULL value? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the problem really that it doesn't compile?  `NULL` is `void *`, such that it should be legitimate (to the compiler) to pass it to `DelBook()`

Comment: It's perfectly fine to `delete NULL;`

Comment: @BrianCain, well, `DelBook(NULL)` in a parameter list is not even a parameter, so I guess it's just an illustration.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker, indeed, I read it as an illustration.  However he asks "how can i make it compile..." -- I assumed this meant "how can I make (some invocation of `DelBook(NULL)`, or perhaps the declaration of `DelBook(Book *X)`."

Comment: @BrianCain, I have to admit the last sentence (question?) is a bit cryptic, but there's an implementation of `DelBook` above, which is quite fine…

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker, sure.  But we've all seen questions which omit something critical (e.g. the problem was really that "`DelBook(null)`" generates a compiler error that the submitter might attribute to the runtime attempt to `delete` it.)   Which is why I asked for clarification on the problem definition. :)

Comment: @BrianCain, yes, clarification may be of help. I'm not saying your comment is invalid, we're both just doing our best at guessing :)

Comment: i'm quite getting 2 errors something like expression must have a pointer or handle type and error expected a type specifier

Comment: @BrianCain `NULL` can be many things, but it cannot be `void*`; `NULL` is required to have an integral type.  (The best implementations I've seen use something like `__nullptr`, a special built in, so that they can generate a warning if the integer isn't converted immediately to a pointer.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as `DelBook` only invokes `delete` — nothing happens, it's a no-op. (and it is possible to invoke your `DelBook` with `NULL` as a parameter value, no extra action needed).

Answer (score 0):

`NULL` is a valid pointer: it points to memory location zero. Therefore you can pass NULL into a function that takes a `Book*` pointer, because it IS a `Book*` pointer.

Additionally, NULL is special and doesn't need to be cast to `Book*` - you do not need to say `DelBook((Book*)NULL)`. Therefore, the program should compile already.

Deleting a null pointer does nothing, so you don't need a sanity check. However if you need to do something with a member of the `Book` class, you must check it is not NULL first:

```
static void DelBook(Book * X)
{
    if (X){
        x->tidyUpBeforeDeletion();
        delete X;
    }
}
```

Failure to check this will result in a segfault - this is dereferencing a null pointer and is very bad news.

Comment: `NULL` is _not_ a pointer (valid or not).  It converts implicitly to a null pointer of any type.  Whether a null pointer is a valid pointer or not depends on what you do with it (but it _is_ valid as an operand to `delete`).

Answer (score -2):

Passing NULL itself usually isn't a problem. It's basically 0. Deleting NULL probably has no effect